# How to connect my realme phone for debuging

Tags: android, debugging, adb

I want to Connect my realme narzo 10a phone to Android Studio I tried many times but got error 'Adb is Unable'

Comment: 1. Turn On Developer Option, 2. Turn On USB Debugging, 3. Turn On Insall Via USB

Comment: In Android newer versions turn on install via usb is deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

1)Turn on developer options
2) Turn on usb debugging

If it doesn't show
Try to change
Usb charging to file transfer

It works for me

Answer (score 2):

Phone Setting -> About Phone -> Version(Tap 7 times) -> Go Back -> Additional Setting -> Developer Option -> Enter the Captcha -> USB Debugging(Switch On)

Answer (score 1):

Update device drivers on your system according to your phone

Comment: how to update, because  I didn't find the device driver on realme official website.
Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to turn on developer mode in your phone. Then go to the developer options and turn on USB debugging and you are ready to go.

Comment: It seems like your phone was released recently. Maybe ADB doesn't support it yet? You can try update your android studio to the newest version to see if it works.

Comment: Yes, I purchased it on 14-09-2020.

Answer (score 1):

I f your device is not showing in cmd when adb devices command or flutter devices command. Or not showing a number.
Solution 1: just install an oppo pc suite in computer and then connect the phone and turn on USB debugging. There you are phone will prompt an RSA key permission. Realme is actually a oppo so download oppo pc suite. Ok good luck it worked for my realme 1. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had been facing same issue with my realme 5 smartphone. After installing Realme USB adb drivers for windows, issue got resolved.

Link -> [Click here.](https://www.thecustomdroid.com/oppo-realme-usb-drivers/)

Just visit the link and follow till step 7. At step 8 click on "Let me pick from a list of available drivers on my computer" and go to the folder usb drivers and click on .inf file.

Click on next. Now windows will detect your realme smartphone.
It worked for me. Hope it'll work for you too. :)

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y81mA.jpg)

In device manager, you will see your device under portable devices
Update its driver> choose automatically.

From this my problem resolved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above options work, try going to
'Other wireless connections'-> 'USB Tethering'
Please turn it on if it is turned OFF.
Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I am using "realmi 8i" and in addition to turning on USB debugging, I had to also select RNDIS (USB Ethernet) as USB Configuration

This setting can be found in System Settings > Developer options.

[image: USB Configuration settings - Realmi 8i]